# Vagrant/VirtualBox not releasing private IP

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-provision

Perhaps this is expected behavior, but more likely I am doing something wrong.

In provisioning vagrant, I bind to a private network:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: 10.24.13.9
```

That works great the first time.

So if I'm done with the box for now, and I `vagrant suspend` and `vagrant destroy` I would expect the IP to be released so that if I provision that vagrant box again, I can again bind to that IP.

At this point, `ifconfig` still shows vboxnet0 in place.

So if I `vagrant up --provision` again, (have tried `vagrant reload` after), the instance cannot bind to the private IP.  The setup of the private network IP just fails silently.

My only workaround right now is to manually remove then recreate vboxnet0:

```
VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet0
VBoxManage hostonlyif create
```

Is this really the expected behavior or am I missing something?  Should the IP not be released once the box is removed?

Comment: The network will remain, the IP will just disappear if the box is not active (there's no "reservation", so it's hard to use the word "release"). The question is mostly a story written in English. Please show more code and results (if something is silent, put a remark, but show the actual flow).

Comment: What other code do you need me to provide?  I could dump my whole vagrant file but there isn't much else there.  I think you are right that the network remains, but the problem still remains that `vagrant up --provision` doesn't correctly setup a network unless I remove then create the vagrant network  and then `vagrant reload`.